# SplFixedArray seems slower than array()

Tags: php, arrays, spl

Everyone says [SplFixedArray is faster than array()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11831076/569976) but...

```
<?php 
$max_el = 256;

$a = array(); 
$c = new SplFixedArray($max_el); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_el; $i++) { 
   $a[$i] = $c[$i] = mt_rand(0, 1000); 
} 

$start = microtime(true); 
for ($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < $max_el; $i++) { 
      $x = $a[$i]; 
   } 
} 
$elapsed0 = microtime(true) - $start; 

$start = microtime(true); 
for ($j = 0; $j < 100000; $j++) { 
   for ($i = 0; $i < $max_el; $i++) { 
      $x = $c[$i]; 
   } 
} 
$elapsed2 = microtime(true) - $start; 

echo "Elapsed time: $elapsed0\r\n"; 
echo "Elapsed time: $elapsed2";
```

The output of that is as follows:

```
Elapsed time: 1.3631780147552
Elapsed time: 2.0408799648285
```

So with 256 elements array() seems faster.

Here are my results with 1024 elements:

```
Elapsed time: 5.6066889762878
Elapsed time: 7.7747831344604
```

Another win for array().

With 10*1024 elements:

```
Elapsed time: 57.000520944595
Elapsed time: 88.719652891159
```

Props, once again, for array().

When, exactly, is SplFixedArray() supposed to be faster?

Comment: your benchmark is wrong as a per not considering CPU, memory and cache that are going underneath the running code. You should also consider to run 2 different processes for have a better benchmark, The GC could be kicked in too.
Also looping 10000 times always the same reading operation is higly cached and not sure is a real world scenario neither. 
Please also include the assignment phase that you are combinging togheter to be benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

[The page that's linked to in the earlier thread](http://www.johnciacia.com/2011/02/01/array-vs-splfixedarray/) that you mentioned seems to talk mostly about write times and memory usage. Here, you're only looking at read times.