# SplFixedArray is much slower and much more memory hungry than array, PHP8.3

Tags: php, arrays, performance, spl

Using PHP8.3.0, testing SplFixedArray, I have this sample code

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

$res = [];
$t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1_000_000; ++$i) {
    if (1) {
        $new = new SplFixedArray(3);
        $new[0] = "foo";
        $new[1] = "bar";
        $new[2] = "baz";
        $res[] = $new;
    } else {
        $res[] = [
            0 => "foo",
            1 => "bar",
            2 => "baz",
        ];
    }
}
$t = microtime(true) - $t;
var_dump(
    [
        'memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024' => memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024,
        'memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024 / 1024' => memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024 / 1024,
        't' => $t,
    ]
);
```

and when I benchmark it with hyperfine, first using arrays and then using SplFixedArray:

```bash
$ hyperfine --warmup 10 'php spl.php'
Benchmark 1: php spl.php
  Time (mean ± σ):      52.7 ms ±   0.8 ms    [User: 43.6 ms, System: 6.0 ms]
  Range (min … max):    51.4 ms …  56.2 ms    57 runs
 
$ hyperfine --warmup 10 'php spl.php'
Benchmark 1: php spl.php
  Time (mean ± σ):     321.1 ms ±   6.1 ms    [User: 267.6 ms, System: 34.8 ms]
  Range (min … max):   315.6 ms … 335.9 ms    10 runs
```

the array method average 52ms, SplFixedArray averaged 321ms

And when I look at memory consumption,

```bash
$ time php spl.php 
/home/hans/projects/headless-chomium-recorder/tests/hans/spl.php:23:
array(3) {
  'memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024' =>
  double(26.0078125)
  'memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024 / 1024' =>
  double(16.383125305176)
  't' =>
  double(0.047396898269653)
}

real    0m0.060s
user    0m0.038s
sys     0m0.018s
$ time php spl.php 
/home/hans/projects/headless-chomium-recorder/tests/hans/spl.php:23:
array(3) {
  'memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024' =>
  double(214.00390625)
  'memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024 / 1024' =>
  double(210.30303955078)
  't' =>
  double(0.28029799461365)
}

real    0m0.321s
user    0m0.301s
sys     0m0.000s
```

array use 26MB RAM, SplFixedArray use 214MB RAM..

Seems that array is much better than SplFixedArray with both in memory consumption and speed,

Quoting the [SplFixedArray documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php):

> The advantage is that it uses less memory than a standard array.

But I see the exact opposite effect, for me SplFixedArray seems to be using ~8 times more memory, why?

Comment: Wonder if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827668/does-really-splfixedarray-perform-better-than-arrays helps, you are creating a large number of small arrays rather than one large array.  This makes a big difference

Comment: SplFixedArray has been worse than the standard array since somewhere around PHP7 when standard array performance was _vastly_ improved. At this point SplFixedArray basically just exists for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Sammitch, I tweaked the code to use `$res =  new SplFixedArray(1_000_001);` and `$res[$i] = 1;` and `$res = [];`.  The SplFixedArray version used 17MB vs 26MB for a normal array.

Comment: Yeah I did pretty much the same thing just now. It's still slightly slower than a regular array, but it does use less memory. I think OP's getting bogged down in overhead creating a million tiny array objects. Also there's surely more to an application than creating/filling arrays. OP needs to benchmark the _actual application_ against the options to see if it's beneficial or not.